# How to force widgets in QGridLayout be not equally spaced?

Tags: c++, qt

```
qGridLayout.addWidget(button1,    3,0,1,1, Qt::AlignBottom);
//qGridLayout.addWidget(button2,    3,1,1,1, Qt::AlignBottom);
// is there a way to make button1/3/4 stay at cell 1/3/4
// even if button2 is hidden
qGridLayout.addWidget(button3,    3,2,1,1, Qt::AlignBottom);
qGridLayout.addWidget(button4,    3,3,1,1, Qt::AlignBottom);
```

The problem I'm having is that, when I hide `button2`, `button1/3/4` becomes automatically equally spaced.

I tried

```
qGridLayout.addItem(new QSpacerItem,3,1,1,1, Qt::AlignBottom);
```

but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

```
qGridLayout.addItem(new QSpacerItem((1, 
                                     1, 
                                     QSizePolicy::Expanding, 
                                     QSizePolicy::Preferred),
                    3,1,1,4, 
                    Qt::AlignTop);
```

My current solution is to add a spacer item above the row of buttons to force it to have 4 equally spaced cells(2nd cell doesn't shrink to nothing even if button2 is hidden).

The reason not to put spacer directly into button2's position is that the spacer will disrupt the layout when button2 is shown and co-exist with the spacer.

Answer (score 0):

Your solution looks fine for me. But, If you wish to get this done without adding a new row to your grid layout, you can use following class.

```
class Hider : public QObject
{    
public:
    Hider(QObject* pParent = 0) : QObject(pParent) {}
    bool eventFilter(QObject* pObject, QEvent* pEvent)
    {
        return pEvent->type() == QEvent::Paint;
    }

    void hide(QWidget* pWidget)
    {
        pWidget->installEventFilter(this);
        pWidget->update();
    }

    void unhide(QWidget* pWidget)
    {
        pWidget->removeEventFilter(this);
        pWidget->update();
    }
};
```

Keep a `Hider` object as a class variable. When you want to hide the button,

```
hider->hide(button2);
```

And when you want to show button again,

```
hider->unhide(button2);
```

Hider filters out all paint events of the widget it hides, making the widget not to be drawn but widget keeps its space in the layout.